# pandas multiple filter row operator

Tags: python

I want to apply multiple row filters on the dataframe.
Below is how the dataframe looks:

```
                        Issue Type                      Status      Orac
            0           Risk Event  Closed - Actions    Completed   Orac
            1           Conformance Testing             Open        Orac
            2           Risk Event                      Draft       Orac
            3           Risk Event                      Open        Orac
            4           Risk Event  Closed - Actions    Completed   Orac
```

and this is the code i formulated to the dataframe:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)

df = xl.parse('Detailed Issue List Report by O')


dfo = df({'Issue Type':['Lessons Learnt','Other Control Issues']},
     {'Status':['Open','Open - Actions Completed']})


df1 = dfo[['Issue Type', 'Status']]


df1['Orac'] = pd.Series('Orac', index=df1.index)
```

Now I want to filter for **Issue type** in ('lesson learnt','other issues','risk event') and **Status** in ('Open', 'Open - Actions Completed')

I got this error:
line 16, in

```
 dfo = df({'Issue Type':['Lessons Learnt','Other Control Issues']})
          builtins.TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

on this line:

```
 dfo = df({'Issue Type':['Lessons Learnt','Other Control Issues']},
          {'Status':['Open','Open - Actions Completed']})
```

Please assist.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas` method called `.loc` to easily achieve this:

```
issueLst = ['lesson learnt','other issues','risk event']
statusLst = ['Open','Open - Actions Completed']
df1 = df1.loc[df1['Issue Type'].isin(issueLst) & df1.loc[df1['Status'].isin(statusLst]
```

EDIT: Your error is because you are trying to call df(), which isn't a function

Comment: Good day, i applied this " issueLst = ['lesson learnt','other issues','risk event']
statusLst = ['Open','Open - Actions Completed']

df2 = df1.loc[df['Issue Type'].isin(issueLst) & df1['Status'].isin(statusLst)] ' i got an error